# Не получается обновить дату в БД методом post

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Есть задание добавить возможность обновления даты ,которая лежит в БД через сайт.
Никак не получается это сделать.

Форма отправки:

```html
<form method="post" th:action="'/'+${vacation.get().id}">
    <p>
        <label for="startVac">Start </label>

        <input type="date" id="startVac" name="startVac" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="endVac">End </label>
        <input type="date" id="endVac" name="endVac"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Контроллеры:

```html
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showEdit(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("vacation", vacationRepo.findById(id));
        return "editVacation";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editVacationDate(@PathVariable("id") Integer id,
                                   @RequestParam(name = "startVac")
                                           LocalDate startVac,
                                   @RequestParam(name = "endVac")
                                           LocalDate endVac,
                                   @ModelAttribute Vacation vax
    ) {
        Vacation vacation = vacationRepo.findById(id).get();
        vacation.setStartVacation(startVac);
        vacation.setEndVacation(endVac);
        vacationRepo.save(vacation);
        return "editVacation";
    }
```

Сама модель:

```html
public class Vacation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_vac")
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Employee.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_empl")
    private Employee employee;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private LocalDate startVacation;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private LocalDate endVacation;
```

получаю в ответ:

```html
Sat Apr 25 16:25:40 MSK 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam java.time.LocalDate] for value '2020-04-02T22:22'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2020-04-02T22:22]
```

Возможно вопрос тривиальный,но я с ним долго провозился перед тем , как написать сюда.
выручайте!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.time.LocalDate'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
>   [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam
>   java.time.LocalDate] for value '2020-04-02T22:22'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value
>   [2020-04-02T22:22]

В этой ошибке нет ничего удивительного. Данные формы приходят как `String`, а Вы их пытаетесь получить в параметре, как `LocalDate`.

Попробуйте использовать строковые параметры с последующим преобразованием.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editVacationDate(@PathVariable("id") Integer id,
                                   @RequestParam(name = "startVac")
                                           String startVac,
                                   @RequestParam(name = "endVac")
                                           String endVac,
                                   @ModelAttribute Vacation vax
    ) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Vacation vacation = vacationRepo.findById(id).get();
        vacation.setStartVacation(dtf.parseLocalDate(startVac));
        vacation.setEndVacation(dtf.parseLocalDate(endVac));
        vacationRepo.save(vacation);
        return "editVacation";
    }
```

Формат для `DateTimeFormatter` укажите свой, если тот, что я привёл в примере не подойдёт.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку , но теперь форматируя через стандартный способ.:
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);
        String s = startVac;
        String e = endVac;
        LocalDate sdate = LocalDate.parse(s, dtf);
        LocalDate edate = LocalDate.parse(e, dtf);
Vacation vacation = vacationRepo.findById(id).get();
   vacation.setStartVacation(LocalDate.parse(dtf.format(sdate)));
        vacation.setEndVacation(LocalDate.parse(dtf.format(edate)));
        vacationRepo.save(vacation);

Выдает: Text '2020-04-01' could not be parsed at index 4

Comment: @MojoChannel, посмотрите в отладчике, в каком формате к вам приходит строка с датой. Под него и пишите `pattern`.